# what "unknown tls.Config field" Error Means?

Tags: go

While I compile a go language code using "go install", I got the following error:

> ./xyzcheck.go:34: unknown tls.Config field 'EarlyCCS' in struct literal

here is the code that make that error

```
conn, err = tls.Dial("tcp", target, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, EarlyCCS: 2})
if err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("\x1b[31mXYZ Check is OK.\x1b[0m\n")
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

I googled this error but no luck.

If anyone can tell me what is the reason for this error? and how can I fix it. it will be great.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: Make sure you're using at least Go 1.2

Comment: how can I update it using the terminal?

Comment: Documentation: http://golang.org/doc/install#tarball

Comment: I'm updating it. thanks, but what is the reason for that error??

Comment: @kingasmk You're trying to set the ABC field when creating a tls.Config struct. But the tls.Config struct does not have an ABC field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABC: 2 is not a valid parameter for config.  There is documentation on config settings for tls here: http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config

Comment: Actually "ABC" is an example, I don't like to mention the right field name, but in the same time I surfed this page before and the right field is not in the available fields.

Comment: why the developer use a field that in not available in the config struct?

Comment: We won't be able to help you if can't give the correct field.  Why don't you ask your developer?

Comment: I have updated it. It's open source code and I couldn't find the developer contacts.

Comment: EarlyCCS was likely deprecated, currently CCS only has one protocol type so you should be fine to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The author has a patch that needs to be applied to the tls package.  This was clearly explained on his blog page where you obtained this script.

Apply the patch to the tls package, re-run the script and it will work.